# React-native camera showing blank screen

Tags: react-native, react-native-camera

Not able to see the camera , showing blank screen on screen using it on real device.

Below is my code for the same

```js
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Text, TouchableOpacity, View } from 'react-native';
import { RNCamera } from 'react-native-camera';

export default function Create() {
    const cameraRef = useRef();

    const takePicture = async () => {
        // if (this.camera) {
        //  const options = { quality: 0.5, base64: true };
        //  const data = await this.camera.takePictureAsync(options);
        //  console.log(data.uri);
        // }
    };
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <RNCamera
                ref={cameraRef}
                style={styles.preview}
                type={RNCamera.Constants.Type.back}
                flashMode={RNCamera.Constants.FlashMode.on}
                androidCameraPermissionOptions={{
                    title: 'Permission to use camera',
                    message: 'We need your permission to use your camera',
                    buttonPositive: 'Ok',
                    buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
                }}
                androidRecordAudioPermissionOptions={{
                    title: 'Permission to use audio recording',
                    message: 'We need your permission to use your audio',
                    buttonPositive: 'Ok',
                    buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
                }}
            />
            <View style={{ flex: 0, flexDirection: 'row', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.capture}>
                    <Text style={{ fontSize: 14 }}> SNAP </Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        flexDirection: 'column',
        backgroundColor: 'black',
    },
    preview: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'flex-end',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    capture: {
        flex: 0,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        borderRadius: 5,
        padding: 15,
        paddingHorizontal: 20,
        alignSelf: 'center',
        margin: 20,
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by removing `android:hardwareAccelerated="false"` from android/src/main/mainfest